# When you lift a box from the floor, the potential energy changes but kinetic energy does not change. Does it violate conservation of energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation, work, potential-energy

Please try and answer this question.

Comment: No. Your energy decreases. Your body burns more fat and sugar, you exhales more CO2. This chemical energy is converted to the potential energy of the box.

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't. You are forgetting something:

Someone has lifted the box and so the chemical energy that was stored in the human body was finally converted into potential energy on the box .

Now let's consider an opposite scenario: You leave a box from height $h$ in order to execute a free fall. So in the beginning it has a PE of $mgh$ and zero KE. During it's fall to the ground, part of the PE is converted to KE and in every point of its trip the sum of it's PE and KE is equal to the initial PE of $mgh$. Finally the box reaches the ground and after some bounces comes to a stop. Did the KE of the box just disappeared? The answer is no, it just converted into heat and sound in order to the energy conservation principle.

Answer (score 3):

The assumption you have implied is that the box starts from rest and finishes up at rest (or starts and finishes with the same speed).

The thing that you not stated is the system that you are considering.

One system which can be considered is the box by itself.
It will be subjected to two external forces which are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction.
The upward force that you exert on the box and the downward force due to the gravitational attraction on the box due to the Earth.
So the net force on the box is zero and no work is done on the box and so its kinetic energy stays constant.
You have done positive work whilst lifting the box that comes from the chemical energy in your body and the gravitational force on the box due to the Earth has done an equal amount of negative work on the box.

Now consider the box and the Earth as the system.
You exerting an external force on the system do positive work on the box as you lift it and push the Earth the other way and that comes from the chemical energy in your body.
The system (box and Earth) gain gravitational potential energy (they end up further apart) equal to the amount of work that you have done on the box.
The box and the Earth start from rest and finish at rest so there is no change in the kinetic energy of the system.

Answer (score 2):

No it does not. Since the potential energy it gained, was provided by the work of the force that lifted it, so energy just got transferred/converted to potential energy.